# How can the general Green's function of a linear homogeneous differential equation be derived?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node49.html) nice tutorial, it is just stated that generally the Green's Function of the linear homogeneous differential equation (eq1 in the tutorial)

$$ L y_n(x) + \lambda_n w(x)y_n(x) = 0 $$

can be written in terms of the Eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$ and Eigenvalues $\lambda$ as (eq9 in the tutorial)

$$ G_{\lambda}(x,x') = \sum\limits_n \frac{y_n(x)y^{*}(x')}{\lambda - \lambda_n}$$

The author writes that he derived it in class, but this does not help me.

So can somebody explain the proof to me, or give some hints how it works? I would appreciate answers at about the same level as the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that the eigenfunctions $y_n$ form an orthogonal basis of the linear operator $L$ that satisfy

$$\sum_n w(x) y_n(x) y_n^* (x') = \delta(x-x') $$

where the $*$ denotes complex conjugation.

Also, the Green's function may be expressed in terms of the orthogonal basis functions:

$$G(x,x') = \sum_n a_n(x') y_n(x)$$

Consider the defining equation for the Green's function

$$L \, G(x,x') + \lambda w(x) G(x,x') = \delta(x-x')$$

where

$$L \, G(x,x') = \sum_n a_n(x') L \,y_n(x) = - \sum_n a_n(x') \lambda_n w(x) \,y_n(x)$$

and the defining equation may be rewritten as

$$\sum_n a_n(x') (\lambda - \lambda_n) w(x) y_n(x) = \sum_n w(x) y_n(x) y_n^* (x')$$

or

$$\sum_n [a_n(x') (\lambda - \lambda_n) -  y_n^* (x')] w(x) y_n(x) = 0$$

Because the $y_n$ form an orthogonal basis set, we can consider each term in the sum individually and conclude that

$$a_n(x') = \frac{y_n^*(x')}{\lambda-\lambda_n}$$

and therefore

$$G(x,x') = \sum_n \frac{y_n(x) y_n^*(x')}{\lambda-\lambda_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for this nice and very clear step by step derivation, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ron Gordon So what is $\lambda$ here? Who determines that? How does this method match with the method you said here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284870/greens-function-for-fracd2dx2-frac14

Comment: @user6818: $\lambda$ defines the particular differential operator that has that particular Green's function.  The $\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of that differential operator, i.e. allowed values of $\lambda$ when the result of applying the differential operator to a function is a scalar times that function.

Comment: And how does this version of the Green's function compare to the one I found for a particular differential operator?  Note that here, $\lambda = 1/4$. The sum over eigenfunctions/eigenvalues should agree with the specific results in that problem, although I have not worked that out.

Comment: @RonGordon So what are the $\lambda_n$ in that other question? (..aren't both the $\lambda _n$ also 1/4 for both the eigen functions and then here the denominator becomes 0..) And how will you get a split function from this formalism? In that other question how does $y(0)$ condition become the $G(x<x')$ condition and vice-versa for $y(\pi)$? I don't get this translation.

Comment: The $\lambda_n$, again, are the eigenvalues of the diff. operator.  These correspond to a **different equation** than that satisfied by the Green's function, which is characterized by the value of $\lambda$.  I know, a little confusing.  As for the equivalence between the versions, I have not worked it out.  Here is a reference, though, that illustrates these two differing versions being considered in the same problem:  http://physics.bu.edu/~pankajm/LN/LNGF1.pdf

Comment: @RonGordon I guess the point is that $\lambda$ makes sense only when the differential operator is sourced - then arbitrary Lambda are allowed and then the source propagated with this $G_\lamda$. If the source is 0 then only $\lambda$ that makes sense are the $\lambda_n$ - the eigenvalues of the operator. So one never has the $\lambda = \lambda_n$ singularity since one never uses this Green's function in the absence of a source - which will allow lambda to be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: @user6818: correct.